# ReactJS/GatsbyJS Modify All Video Node Instances

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, gatsby

I need to mute all video instances prior to unmuting the clicked instance. What is the best way of initiating this action?

Call to Video Component -- Loops all videos.

```
<ol className="videos">
  {data.allFile.nodes.map((node, i) => {
    return (
      <li key={i} className="video">
        <Video vid={node.publicURL} />
      </li>
    )
  })}
</ol>
```

Video Component -- Outputs video and adds clickhandler for muting and unmuting.

```
import React from 'react'

const Video = (props) => {
  const [mute, setMute] = React.useState(true)

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setMute(!mute)
  }

  return (
    <video autoPlay="1" loop="1" muted={(mute ? true : false)} onClick= {clickHandler}>
      <source src={props.vid} type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  )
}

export default Video
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mute` as a prop on the `Video Component` element, instead of a state on the `Video` component. This way, you can make sure that just ONE Video is unmuted. Example:

```
const VideoList = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);

  <ol className="videos">
    {data.allFile.nodes.map((node) => {
      return (
        <li key={node.id} className="video">
          <Video vid={node.publicURL} mute={active !== node.id} onClick={() => setActive(active !== node.id ? node.id : -1)} />
        </li>
      )
    })}
  </ol>
};

const Video = (props) => {
  return (
    <video autoPlay="1" loop="1" muted={props.mute} onClick={props.onClick}>
      <source src={props.vid} type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  )
}
```

This way, the VideoList component controls if each video is "muted" or not.

Note that using the array index is not the best way to handle this, specially if your videos array can change over time.

EDIT:

If you want to make sure all videos are muted from the first render, just set the default value of the state to `-1`.

`const [active, setActive] = useState(-1);`

Comment: Please explain what you mean by it not being the best way to handle. I'm pulling the videos via graphql. Maybe a linked resource. Also, I'm making your suggested changes to test out. Thanks.

Comment: If your array never changes, then you're good. But if your video has some kind of ID, it's better to use that as a key. Imagine that you have an array [v1, v2, v3] with the videos, then the array somehow gets updated to [v1, v2, v4, v3]. You'll have to re-render v3 completely because your key (array index) has changed. If each video has its own unique id, it's better to use it instead of the array index. If that was the case, v3 would not be re-rendered by the introduction of v4.

Comment: Almost works. Two issues: first, "useState(1)" to set mute as "true"; second, the default setting for all videos should be muted -- currently one video is always playing, and clicking the unmuted video should remute. So I've got to update the mute conditional in some manner.

Comment: I've updated the Keys by your suggestion changing "i" to "node.id".

Comment: So... Let me understand this a bit more. Can you have more than one video unmuted at the same time? If you can, that particular approach won't work. If you want a "mute all" button, just set the state to "-1" and you're good.

Comment: Basically I now need a way to mute by click the one video which may be unmuted. Generally the same way Instagram works. Only one video is unmuted at one time, though you can tap and mute that video.

Comment: The following update to the onClick function resolves the issue: onClick={() => (active !== node.id ? setActive(node.id) : setActive(-1))}

Comment: Update your answer and I'll mark as solved. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: There you go! I’ve also fixed the key and the mute props